# How to put a space between firstName and lastName

Tags: java

I do not know why my lastName and firstName are printing without a space between them.  Please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LastNameFirstNameChapter3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName; // Users First Name
    String lastName;  // Users Last Name
    String age;          // Users Age

    System.out.print("Enter Your First Name: ");
    firstName = stdIn.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println("Hello " +""+ firstName + "!");
    System.out.print("Please Enter Your Last Name: ");
    lastName = stdIn.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println("Hello " + firstName +""+ lastName + "!");
    System.out.print("Enter Your Age: ");
    age = stdIn.nextLine(); 
    } // end main
}     // end class LastNameFirstNameChapter3
```

Comment: -1 that `space` tag. And you never actually put a space between `firstName` and `lastName`, just an empty string.

Comment: Have you tried putting a space between the quotes?

Comment: Thank you.  Bone head mistake.  I'm brand new to code

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LastNameFirstNameChapter3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName; // Users First Name
    String lastName;  // Users Last Name
    String age;          // Users Age

    System.out.print("Enter Your First Name: ");
    firstName = stdIn.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println("Hello " +" "+ firstName + "!");
    System.out.print("Please Enter Your Last Name: ");
    lastName = stdIn.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println("Hello " + firstName +" "+ lastName + "!");
    System.out.print("Enter Your Age: ");
    age = stdIn.nextLine(); 
    } // end main
}
```

Comment: Thank you...almost as soon as I posted the question I realized I was missing the "space".